iostream not found with g++ and clang on macos
I'm trying to compile StegHide from source and I got an error message, saying that iostream can't be found.
I wrote the following program and compiled it with -std set to all standards that my system has:
#include <iostream>
int main() {return 0;}

This gives this error message:
test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
    1 | #include <iostream>

The /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1 dir only contains the __cxx_version file. Is there anything I need to (re)install?
Edit:
iostream was in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/, but how can I make g++/clang search this path by default?
